# CheckedListBox - how to set which parameter of an object to display?

Tags: c#, datasource, checkedlistbox

I have a problem with CheckedListBox.
I have a list of objects:

```
private WinPcapDeviceList deviceList = WinPcapDeviceList.Instance;
```

This contains WinPcapDevice objects.
I wanted to add the list as a datasource for the ChecklistBox

```
CheckList.DataSource = devices;
```

When i start the program the output is not very helpful for user as it looks something like this: [checkedlistbox with WinPcapDeviceList as datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpIww.png)

I want it to look like this: [checkedlistbox with description of devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MxDD.png)

So in the list is only the description of the devices, here's how you can get the description:

```
WinPcapDevice.Description();
```

How can i set which property of the object will be diplayed?

Comment: What kind of application (Winform, WPF) is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to indicate what property of the source item you want to display using the "DisplayMember" property of CheckedLisbox (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox_members(v=vs.90).aspx).

You example shows that the description comes from a method, so you will perhaps have to create a property with a getter that will call this method.

Hope this will help.

Philippe

Comment: Thanks, I already fixed it with 
            CheckList.ValueMember = "Description"; Both DisplayMember and ValueMember work the same, don't have an idea what is the difference between them, if you know and care to explain I would be glad

Comment: DisplayMember is for display only. ValueMember will be used when you call the "SelectedValue" property on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add items to your `CheckBoxList` or set `DataSource` and `DisplayMember`. Just get `Name` from device list

Use `foreach` loop like this

```
WinPcapDeviceList devices = WinPcapDeviceList.Instance;

            foreach (WinPcapDevice dev in devices)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dev.Name);
            }
```

Using `DataSource` and `DisplayValue` property

```
      checkedListBox1.DataSource = devices;
      checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```